# Phonegap and Samsung Pocket buttons overlappping

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I'm currently developing a jQuery Mobile app that runs in Phonegap. I'm testing the app on a Samsung pocket. As such I'm currently running into the following problem as seen in the picture.

[image]

Case in my HTML file I'm using the `target-densitydpi=device-dpi` so I'd assume that the phone adjusts based on this? Would the phone not scale down and allow for the buttons to fit?

I'm not entirely sure how to fix this?? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple answer really. In the body tag just adjust the font:

```
body{

font-size:100%

}
```